# Не переустанавливается jdk

Tags: java, jdk11

Я новичок в java, несколько дней назад хотел переустановить java на новую версию jdk 13 а у меня стоял 1.8_141, установил jdk 13 а путях все прописал, захожу в cmd пишу "java -version", а там старый jdk, пробовал обратно несколько раз переустановить, путь обратно ставил, перезагружал ноут, не помогло.

java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)

Comment: А `javac -version` что показывает?

Comment: >javac -version                                                                                                                                         
javac 13.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команда `>java -version` проверяет версию установленного JRE, Попробуйте проверить командой `>javac -version`. Скорее всего вы забыли поменять пути к JRE. В принципе думаю  можно просто удалить старую версию Java.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо